# How to shrink database on Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Heroku prevents database maintenance activities. How to shrink database?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do on which database? MySQL? Is it that you want to do an `optimize`? Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: The primary database on Heroku is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Still: Please be more specific!

Comment: There was a lot of BLOBs which are currently NULLs. I want to shrink database size to save space. That's all. I can't be more specific. I don't know `optimize` or not optimize. I just want to shrink it by any means.

Comment: AFAIK the only way to reclaim filesystem space is to run a `VACUUM FULL`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-vacuum.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `heroku pg:psql` and run commands such as `VACUUM` or `VACUUM FULL`. Please see the [postgres docs on vacuum](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-vacuum.html) for detailed information.